# If statement won't take the color into account

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I have this If statement that says, If this cell says rehire, and the fill is this color, AND this other cell says hire date, then to delete the row. Right now it is deleting the row if it says rehire in the one and hire date in the other no matter the color of the cell. It isn't taking the color intro consideration. Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

```
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngRows As Long
'Find the last row in Column A
lngRows = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For lngRow = lngRows To 2 Step -1
    If LCase(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lngRow, "A").Value) = "rehire" _
        And ((ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lngRow, "E").FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color) = RGB(255, 199, 206) _
        And LCase(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lngRow, "I").Value) = "hire date") Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(lngRow).EntireRow.Delete _

    End If
Next
```

Actually, now that I look at it, if I go to format cells and go to fill, custom color, it is all 0 and it says there is no fill. The fill color was done by conditional formatting. I was using the other number which was 13551615 that I got from the conditional formatting, but that wasn't working either. The code is deleting lines if there is no fill which it shouldnt be because it doesn't meet all 3 requirements. Am I wrong in thinking this?

Comment: "The fill color was done by conditional formatting" - perhaps you could use that formula too, to determine if the cell is colored, rather than relying on the fill?

Comment: @BruceWayne I am not sure how I would do that. The conditional formatting is done by selecting a column, then using a "With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior". I am not sure where I would put the with statement I guess. Around the If statement or something?

Comment: @BruceWayne I actually found an answer that ended up working after a while of searching. Check my answer if you want to see how to do it : ) Thanks Batman!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The condition "FormatConditions" does not work for this conditional formatting. You need to use DisplayFormat.Interior.Color for it to work. So first I used this code to find what color it actually was. I am sure you can edit it to make it only display the single cell I just used this because it didn't matter and I wanted to check the colors.

```
Sub GetTheColors()
For i = 1 to 100
 For j = 1 to 10
      Cells(i,j+10) = Cells(i,j).FormatConditions.Interior.ColorIndex
 Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Then once I had my color, which for the light red fill from conditional formatting mine was 38, I then changed my code to look like this, and it then needed ALL 3 conditions to be true for it to delete the row.

```
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngRows As Long
'Find the last row in Column A
lngRows = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For lngRow = lngRows To 2 Step -1
    If LCase(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lngRow, "A").Value) = "rehire" _
        And ((ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lngRow, "E").DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex) = 38 _
        And LCase(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lngRow, "I").Value) = "hire date") Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(lngRow).EntireRow.Delete _

    End If
Next
```

So I basically just changed the FormatConditions and that number, to DisplayFormat.Interior.Color with my new color I found. This worked with conditional formatting.